# TypeScript error when using switch case descrimination (TS2367)

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors

Is my logic working differently that I intend or does the compiler not understand what I am trying to do?

Error - Line i4: `This condition will always return true since the types SubjectType.Both | SubjectType.A and SubjectType.B have no overlap.`

```
j1  enum SubjectType {
j2      BOTH,
j3      A,
j4      B,
j5  }

i1  switch ( subjectType: SubjectType ) {
i2      case SubjectType.BOTH
i3      case SubjectType.A:
i4          if( subjectType !== SubjectType.B ) {
i5              //Do thing A
i6          }
i7      case SubjectType.B:
i8          if( subjectType !== SubjectType.A ) {
i9              //Do thing B
i10         }
i11 
i12         break;
i13      default:
i14          throw new TypeError( `Unknown SubjectType ${subjectType} provided` );
i15  }
```

**EDIT:**
My logic was in fact, incorrect.

```
i1  switch ( subjectType: SubjectType ) {
i2      case SubjectType.BOTH
i3      case SubjectType.A:
i4          //Do thing A, if type A | BOTH
i5
i6      case SubjectType.B:
i7          if( subjectType !== SubjectType.A ) {
i8              //Do thing B
i9          }
i10 
i11         break;
i12      default:
i13          throw new TypeError( `Unknown SubjectType ${subjectType} provided` );
i14  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subjectType` variable/const can have only 3 states:`A`, `B` and `BOTH`.
COnsider this example:

```js
enum SubjectType {
    BOTH,
    A,
    B,
}
const subjectType: SubjectType = null as any

function foo() {
    switch (subjectType) {
     case SubjectType.BOTH:
     case SubjectType.A:
        if (subjectType !== SubjectType.B) {
            //Do thing A
        }
     case SubjectType.B:
        if (subjectType !== SubjectType.A) {
            //Do thing B
        }

        break;
      default:
        throw new TypeError(`Unknown SubjectType ${subjectType} provided`);
    }
}
```

These two rows inside `switch`:

```js
case SubjectType.BOTH:
case SubjectType.A:
```

mean that `subjectType` is one of `BOTH` or `A`, but not `B`.

Then, you are trying to compare `subjectType` with `B` `if (subjectType !== SubjectType.B) {`,
but it is clear for TS and me that `subjectType` in this case just can't be `B`.

Comment: I see, fall through got me confused, but you are correct.  If subjectType is SubjectType.B, that block won't execute, so don't even bother checking; just do it!